# Code needed to determine the smallest k that the equation will fail by brute force

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

I find one of the suggested solution to this problem a little bit questionable:

“If N is divisible by 1, 2, 3,. . . M, then N must also be divisible by M + 1, M + 2, M + 3, . . . M + k for k is a positive integer.”

One of the suggested solution is:$$M=1+\prod_{p\leq k+1} p^{1+\lfloor \log_p (k+1)\rfloor}$$

This gives $M=37$ for $k=2$ and $M=1+8\cdot 9=73$ for $k=3$.

But the one who give this formula also claimed that this formula does not guarantee for the best value of M, it just give a value of M.

In lieu to this, I believe that this formula will fail at some k as k is considerably large. My question is what must be the code to be encoded in mathematica so that I'll be able to determine the smallest k it will fail by brute force. Manual computation is time consuming., I already tried up to k = 12... any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the actual code you're working with? Having real, copyable code in your question increases the likelihood someone will take it upon themselves to write up an answer. One other thing, what do you mean the "best value of M"?

Comment: Is the formula for `M`, correct? For `k=2`, I get `M = 37`.

Comment: aw sorry mistype.. you're correct it must be 37 then

Comment: @rosa Likewise for `k=3`, `M` is `1153`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What it means is that for k = 2, M = 37 that is the LCM(1,2,3,4 ....37) = LCM(1,2,3,4,...38) = LCM (1,2,3,4, ...,39) for M + 1 and M + 2,,, based on the suggested formula it does not include M + 3 which is 40 but LCM(1,2,3,4....40) although it is also included in the set. the formula does not give the best value M .. but only gives M as suggested value.

Comment: @rosa so by "best" you mean the minimal `M` that satisfies the conditions? My point is that "best" is ambiguous and provides no objective function to optimize.

Comment: @AnjanKumar p there in the formula only restricts on prime numbers that is, 
M = 1 + 2^(1+ ⌊〖log〗_2 (4)⌋ )  ∙ 3^(1+ ⌊〖log〗_3 (4)⌋ )  
M = 1 + 2^(1+ 2)  ∙ 3^(1+ 1)
M = 1 + 2^3  ∙ 3^2
M = 1 + 8 ∙ 9
M = 73

Comment: @somehow yes.. as long as M + k is not prime.

Comment: @rosa Thank you. Please add that information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand the question correctly you want to find the minimal `M` such that given `k`, this holds:

```
Equal@@Table[LCM@@Range[M+p], {p, 0, k-1}]
```

Or rather you want to find a way to know how far off your `M` is.

I can't provide you with a close-form solution for this. But I can show how drastically off that formula is. Here's a memoized recursive, unoptimized, clumsy, procedural search for `M` (but it took like 2 seconds to write, so there you are):

```
Clear[findM];
findM[1] = 5;
findM[k_] :=
 findM[k] =
  Block[{
    mTest = findM[k - 1],
    oldVal,
    newVal,
    hits = 1
    },
   oldVal = LCM @@ Range[mTest];
   While[hits < k + 1,
    If[oldVal === (newVal = LCM @@ Range[++mTest]),
     hits++,
     oldVal = newVal;
     hits = 1
     ]
    ];
   mTest - k
   ]
```

And here's that testing function:

```
mTest[m_, k_] :=
 Equal @@ Table[LCM @@ Range[m + p], {p, 0, k - 1}]
```

And finally here's the formula for `M` you had:

```
weirdM[k_] :=
 1 +
  Product[
   Power[p, 1 + Floor[Log[p, k + 1]]],
   {p, 2, k + 1}
   ]
```

Now let's compute differences between the found value and the `weirdM` value:

```
weirdM[#] - findM[#] & /@ Range[15]

{0, 24, 1134, 28769, 1036748, 50803112, 6502809512, 1580182732662, \
158018273279862, 19120211066879802, 2753310393630719802, \
465309456523591679708, 91200653478623969279708, \
20520147032690393087999114, 42025261122949925044223999114}
```

You can see `weirdM` blows up way faster than `findM`. And here's what the values should be, if I'm reading the question right:

```
findM /@ Range[15]

{5, 13, 19, 32, 53, 89, 89, 139, 139, 199, 199, 293, 293, 887, 887}
```

And just to check:

```
mTest[findM[#], #] & /@ Range[15]

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, \
True, True, True, True}
```

So, in short, the formula fails to find the minimal such `M` by `k=2` I think. And it fails ever more dramatically as `k` increases.

Do note, though, that this `findM` is mad slow, even with memoization. But I think you want a formula, not a procedure, anyway.

```
findM /@ Range[50] // AbsoluteTiming

{183.835, {5, 13, 19, 32, 53, 89, 89, 139, 139, 199, 199, 293, 293, 
  887, 887, 887, 887, 887, 887, 1129, 1129, 1331, 1331, 1331, 1331, 
  1331, 1331, 1331, 1331, 5591, 5591, 8467, 8467, 9551, 9551, 15683, 
  15683, 15683, 15683, 15683, 15683, 15683, 15683, 19609, 19609, 
  19609, 19609, 19609, 19609, 19609}}
```